# consuming a Rest-API with javascript in the browser

Tags: javascript, rest, browser

I'm writing a sever application in go providing a Rest-API.  If the server gets a GET without JSON-content-type header it serves an empty html-page having a javascript module in its *head*.  This javascript code uses *fetch* to consume the Rest-API and populates then according the *document.body* with content fetched from the server.  Each "link" in the content triggers further calls to the API and corresponding updates to the content.

So far so good.  But I made two irritating observations.

1. (obviously) the "back" and "forward" buttons of the browser stay inactive.  Which seems logical since there are no loaded URLs associated with the content changes.
2. If I come to my Rest-UI from an other page and hit the browser's back-button I get as expected the other page back but if I hit now the browser's forward-button I see the JSON-response from my initial fetch instead of my Rest-UI content.  Reloading my page makes it all good again but I can't offer that behavior to any user :)

Are there common approaches to deal with this behavior? E.g. removing the browser controls completely, feeding the browser-history "by hand" with js-callbacks, caching directives, ... (I'm inexperienced with js)

Comment: Have you tried using the History API? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API

Answer (score 0):

The root of the problem is that I overloaded the response of a GET request on the server-side: if the GET-request accepts JSON the server returns JSON otherwise it returns a html-page with the javascript which consumes the JSON. I. e. the javascript fetch for the JSON is the last GET-response for a given URL and goes as such into the browser's cache associated with that URL.  A solution to that problem which works for me is to send a header with the JSON response turning of caching and signalling the browser with the "Vary"-header that the response depends on the "Accept"-header.  An other solution might be to add distinct endpoints to the server for the Rest-requests.